# How do I factor out the callbacks functionality from this ajax function?

Tags: jquery, ajax, design-patterns

I created a reusable ajax pattern in jQuery. It works well, but it's starting to become messy as I add more actions to it.

Look at the `success` callback. Every time I add a new action, the conditional logic gets messier: `if actionType == foo, then bar` etc...

```
$('.action-panel').delegate('a', 'click', function () {
    var link = $(this),
        actionTypeId = link.data('action-type-id'),

    // Do stuff, like getting the url from the link, etc...
    // Throttle multiple clicks

        $.ajax({ //[snip]

            beforeSend: function () {
                link.toggleClass('on');
            },
            error: function () {
                link.toggleClass('on');
            },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    if (actionTypeId === 4) {
                        // do stuff for action 4
                    }
                    else if (actionTypeId === 2) {
                        // do stuff related to action 2
                    }
                    else if (actionTypeId === 3) {
                        // do stuff related to action 3
                    }
                    // More action types, etc...
                }
                else {
                    link.toggleClass('on');
                }
            // decide to show tooltip or not
            });
        // do some extra stuff like re-enable the link (throtled earlier)
```

I  should factor out the ajax function by itself. But I can't figure out a way to separate the callback conditionals into their own blocks/functions, and pass back the result.

Any ideas? Please bare in mind I'm new to JavaScript and jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have an "action" map like this, saving the action ID and the `function` to execute:

```
var actions = {

  '4' : function () {
    $('.fav-count').text(response.newcount);
    $('.fav-count').toggleClass('on');
  },

  '2' : function() {
    link.siblings('.liked').removeClass('on');
    link.siblings('.count').text(response.newcount);
  }
}
```

Then on the `success` callback you just do:

```
if (response.success) {
   actions[actionTypeId]();
}
```

Note you'll probably have to change a bit things since `link` wont be visible from the callback but you can do something like `actions[actionTypeId](this);` and then have the callbacks receive the link as a parameter.

Comment: I'd recommend identifying the functions with names (instead of numbers) and passing the link and response to the callback so you can make use of them. Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/Lobstrosity/kQtTV/

Comment: Indeed, I was thinking the same thing but it would make the answer longer and probably is just a nice to have. We don't even know if the question's code is real or just an example

Comment: @Lobstrosity and Pablo, thanks guys. I guess I can change the markup to `<a data-action="like"></a>` Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could put all the callbacks in a seperate Object:

```
var success_callbacks = {};
success_callbacks["2"] = function(response) {
    link.siblings('.liked').removeClass('on');
    link.siblings('.count').text(response.newcount);
};
success_callbacks["3"] = function(response) {
    link.siblings('.disliked').removeClass('on');
    link.siblings('.count').text(response.newcount);
};
success_callbacks["4"] = function(response) {
    $('.fav-count').text(response.newcount);
    $('.fav-count').toggleClass('on');
};
```

And then call them in your success handler

```
$('.action-panel').delegate('a', 'click', function () {
    var link = $(this),
        actionTypeId = link.data('action-type-id'),

    // Do stuff, like getting the url from the link, etc...
    // Throttle multiple clicks

    // BEGIN AJAX
    $.ajax({
        context: this,
        dataType: 'json',
        url: url,

        beforeSend: function () {
            link.toggleClass('on');
        },
        error: function () {
            link.toggleClass('on');
        },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.success) {
                success_callbacks[action-type-id](response);
            }
            else {
                link.toggleClass('on');
            }
        // decide to show tooltip or not
        });
    // do some extra stuff like re-enable the link (throtled earlier)
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to use a switch for this.

```
switch (actionTypeId) {
case 4:
    $('.fav-count').text(response.newcount);
    $('.fav-count').toggleClass('on');
    break;
case 2:
    link.siblings('.liked').removeClass('on');
    link.siblings('.count').text(response.newcount);
    break;
case 3:
    link.siblings('.disliked').removeClass('on');
    link.siblings('.count').text(response.newcount);
    break;
default:
    break;
}
```

Note that the first item found true will be executed as long as you have a break in there.

Alternate way: Note the response.success and the NEED for breaks then.

```
switch (true) {
    case !response.success:
        link.toggleClass('on'); 
        break;
    case actionTypeId===4:
        $('.fav-count').text(response.newcount);
        $('.fav-count').toggleClass('on');
        break;
    case actionTypeId===2:
        link.siblings('.liked').removeClass('on');
        link.siblings('.count').text(response.newcount);
        break;
    case actionTypeId===3:
        link.siblings('.disliked').removeClass('on');
        link.siblings('.count').text(response.newcount);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
```